# Dynamic Methods/Rules

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create a product configurator, but according to the requirements, literally every product has a set of rules to validate it. The rules refer to the quantity of underlying components the configuration is made of. 
At the moment the way this is being handled is just storing the "formula" string in the db, and since the UI is in Excel, then when you call a configuration, it comes with the rules as well and you just append a "=" in front of it. Thus, the final product works when quantities or components change.

So I've seen a few similar type of questions being asked, and the answer always seemed to be UJS, however, this is stored in the app itself, correct? The challenge for me is to create a way I can replicate these rules depending on the product, and different products are beeing added all the time, changed, etc, so keeping it in the app to redeploy each time you want to change something seems a bit extreme!

Can anyone think of a good solution? Help!

Answer (score 0):

These are business rules so they'll need to be stored somewhere server-side (they could be mirrored in client-side code but storing them there exclusively is highly inadvisable ;). They could be represented as code, or configuration files, or in a database.

As you suggested, modeling frequently changing rules in source code makes your app brittle. I think the best storage option is your database.

If you need to implement a client-side behavior on a per-product basis, you could use AJAX to send a product ID out to a service which returns a configuration "package" to your (dumb) client.

Would that work? Sounds good to me, anyway. ;)

Comment: Thanks! I've analized different options on how to do it server-side as you mention as this seems to be the only way to make it work. However if I did go that road, for example storing a JS "string" in the Db under each configuration, to be loaded when the configuration is selected, how would that work? (In terms of coding it, I'm a bit lost). Say I have 2 components, A and B, default qty for A is 1 and for B is 2. But the rule says, that I can change A, but if I choose to, B always needs to be double that amount. Or what did you mean by "package"? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: What I'm thinking about is more along the lines of calling out to the server and letting server-side code handle the implementation logic, while keeping the client "dumb." In this scheme you wouldn't store scripts, but rather process the rules and return the results (using JSON as the transport). How about that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here, I'm new to rails, as it's probably apparent by now. So what you're saying is that i should (when a modification to the default is made) is get the rules using json from the server? 
Part 2 of the question would be, how are these rules stored on the server-side? Thanks TK-421!